# Servo/Motor for barrier gate

Tags: arduino-uno, power, motor, servo, robotics

I am working on a small project that will need to check for proper UPC's then if validated, lift a barrier gate to move along cardboard boxes. The Arduino comes in with the gate lifting. I have this barrier gate working with a very small servo that came included with the Arduino Starter Kit, but this could not hold the weight that might be pushing up against it with a longer arm. Has anyone had any experience with something like this or could someone direct of a power supply/servo combo that would be up to the task? These boxes could weigh up to 20 pounds.

Thanks!

Comment: You may find [Robotics Stackexchange](http://robotics.stackexchange.com)  useful for questions like this.

Comment: This is really not an Ardunio question.  Keep in mind also, that a system strong enough to do what you want is also potentially hazardous to people working on or around it, so you will probably end up needing to pay more attention to making it *safe* than you do to making it actually *work*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may **purchase a servo motor with greater torque**.

You may find both DC as well as AC servo's. If you are using it in a real industrial scenario I would suggest you to use the AC, as you may not have to convert the ac power to DC and these motors will need real high current. So it would be better if it works on the main voltage. I did find **[PANASONICs ac servo](https://industrial.panasonic.com/ww/products/motors-compressors/fa-motors/ac-servo-motors)** as google search result.

If you have problems with integrating the greater torque motor to your current system let me know i can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at larger DC gearmotors such as automotive power window or power door motors and use limit switches for position sensing. To power this you would need a 12V power supply capable of at least 5 amps.